# Base64 encoding fails

Tags: c++, crypto++

I am using Crypto++ for other encryption needs; however, I also need to store binary information as ascii text. To do that I have synthesized examples of Crypto++'s base 64 filter into the following block of code.

```
bool saveData(const unsigned char * buffer, size_t length)
{

    int lenb64 = (ceil(length / 3.0) * 4) + 1;
    unsigned char * temp_str = (unsigned char *)malloc(lenb64);

    CryptoPP::ArraySource as(buffer, length, new CryptoPP::Base64Encoder(
        new CryptoPP::ArraySink(temp_str, lenb64)));

    //do something with temp_str.
    free(temp_str); //Then free the tempstr.
    //Return true if do something worked, else false.
}
```

The problem I'm having is that after this operation temp_str is still filled with garbage. I have looked around, and cannot find any examples that do anything other than what I've done above. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CryptoPP::ArraySource` is a `typedef` of [`CryptoPP::StringSource`](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_string_source.html).  The signature of `StringSource`'s relevant constructor is:

```
StringSource(const byte *string,
             size_t length,
             bool pumpAll,
             BufferedTransformation *attachment=NULL);
```

So your third argument which is a pointer to a `CryptoPP::Base64Encoder` is being cast to a `bool`, and the fourth argument is the default `NULL`.

To resolve this, just do:

```
CryptoPP::ArraySource(buffer, length, true,
    new CryptoPP::Base64Encoder(
        new CryptoPP::ArraySink(temp_str, lenb64)));
```

Comment: That's bitten a lot of folks. The C++ language does not make it any better because of pointer-to-bool conversion without a warning (even with `-Wall` and `-Wextra`).

Comment: @noloader Agreed, although VC++ emits a [C4800 warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6801kcy.aspx) at warning level 3: `warning C4800: 'CryptoPP::Base64Encoder *' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)`

Answer (score 0):

> The problem I'm having is that after this operation temp_str is still filled with garbage.

Its actually unintialized data as Fraser pointed out.

The Crypto++ wiki has a page covering the topic at [Missing Data](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Missing_data).

---

You can also avoid the size calculation and buffer management with:

```
string base64;
CryptoPP::ArraySource as(buffer, length, true,
    new CryptoPP::Base64Encoder(
        new CryptoPP::StringSink(base64)));
```